# SQL: Как получить в одном столбце одну цену из разных таблиц

Tags: sql

Есть 4 таблицы: в 1-ой производитель и все модели, во 2-ой, 3-й и 4-й конкретные группы товаров, модели этой группы и цены. Требуется создать запрос, результатом которого должна стать таблица производитель и цены всех его продуктов (два столбца).
Связь у таблиц по моделям. У меня запрос следующий:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product.model, pc.price, laptop.price, printer.price
FROM product 
FULL JOIN pc ON product.model=pc.model 
FULL JOIN laptop ON product.model=laptop.model 
FULL JOIN printer ON product.model=printer.model 
WHERE product.maker = 'B'
```

Результат:

```
model   price     price     price    
1121    850.0000  NULL      NULL    
1750    NULL      1200.0000 NULL
```

А должен быть

```
model   price
1121    850.0000
1750    1200.0000
```

Не понимаю, как свести все цены к одному столбцу.

Comment: Объединить частные таблицы (UNION), и только потом джойнить результат. Либо "схлопнуть" (взять первое not-NULL в списке), используя функцию COALESCE().

Comment: а `full join` то здесь с какой целью написан у вас? `left` в данном случае нужен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш запрос использовать как подзапрос и изменить до вида

```
SELECT product.model as model, COALESCE(pc.price, laptop.price, printer.price) AS price FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT product.model, pc.price, laptop.price, printer.price
    FROM product 
    FULL JOIN pc ON product.model=pc.model 
    FULL JOIN laptop ON product.model=laptop.model 
    FULL JOIN printer ON product.model=printer.model 
    WHERE product.maker = 'B'
) t1
```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал про COALESCE. Без подзапроса но с COALESCE дало правильный результат.